# Connector failed to start 'key.schema' must be set if 'schema.generation.enabled' = false

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was following the guide on using Json source connectorrs. link: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-spooldir/current/connectors/json_source_connector.html

This is my jsonspooldir.properties file.

```
name=JsonSpoolDir
tasks.max=1
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirJsonSourceConnector
input.path=/home/data/unprocessed
input.file.pattern=.*\.json
error.path=/home/data/error
finished.path=/home/data/processed
halt.on.error=false
schema.generation.enabled=true
topic=json-topic
schema.generation.key.name=customer
schema.generation.value.name=customerdata
```

Edit: new error after schema.generation.enabled=true

```
"trace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find any input file(s) to infer schema from.\n\tat shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)\n\tat com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.AbstractSpoolDirSourceConnector.start(AbstractSpoolDirSourceConnector.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:210)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:349)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:332)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:141)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:118)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n"
```

This is the json input file i'm trying to read.

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Thomasin","last_name":"Stanwix","email":"tstanwix0@ycombinator.com","gender":"Genderfluid"}
{"id":2,"first_name":"Berry","last_name":"Dachey","email":"bdachey1@blog.com","gender":"Non-binary"}
{"id":3,"first_name":"Fabio","last_name":"Croad","email":"fcroad2@springer.com","gender":"Female"}
```

Steps to reproduce:
Type the following in cmd prompt:

1. confluent local service start (to start confluent)
2. confluent local services connect connector load json --config /home/jsonspooldir.properties (to load the connector)
3. confluent local services connect connector status json

The following result:

```
{
  "name": "json",
  "connector": {
    "state": "FAILED",
    "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083",
    "trace": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find any input file(s) to infer schema from.\n\tat shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)\n\tat com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.AbstractSpoolDirSourceConnector.start(AbstractSpoolDirSourceConnector.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:210)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:349)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:332)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:141)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:118)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": "source"
}
```

I tried to add schema.generation.key.name=customer
schema.generation.value.name=customerdata into the properties file but i still got the same error

Comment: `.properties` files cannot have spaces around `=`

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to use mysql source connector without having confluent cloud?

Comment: Did that fix the problem? You're not using Confluent Cloud in your question, but yes, the JDBC connector or Debezium are both open source and free to use

Comment: I tried that and i got a new error message

Comment: yes i am using the normal confluent kafka

Comment: "Confluent Kafka" isn't a thing. Please edit your question to include the new errors

Comment: edited to add the new error

Comment: 1) To create a [mcve], can you show one JSON file you are trying to read? 2) According to the docs, If `schema.generation.enabled` set to true, `key.schema` and `value.schema` can be omitted, **but `schema.generation.key.name` and `schema.generation.value.name` must be set**. You do not have these properties

Comment: I added schema.generation.key.name and schema.generation.value.name but still had an error sir

Comment: input.file.pattern=.*\.json might be input.file.pattern=.*\\.json